# z-index not working (not stacked), no background-color set

Tags: html, css, z-index

### Problem

Having two divs and on scroll, we want one to disappear under the next one. We set the positions fixed for the first, relative for the second, correct z-indexes, but on scroll, they just overlap.

```
#first {
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#second {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

### Expected behaviour

On scroll, the first div should disappear into the second one as per z-index stacking rules.

#### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8mf4opsx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Because the second div does not have a default background color set, the background is transparent and the second div can be seen.

The solution is to add a white background to the second div.

```
#first {
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#second {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

#### JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/8mf4opsx/3/